# Pivoting a date and value column to get their combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with this structure:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+------+
| userid |   date    |    item    | rank |
+--------+-----------+------------+------+
|  34444 | 01-Jul-15 | pen        |    3 |
|  34444 | 04-Jul-15 | TV         |    2 |
|  34444 | 09-Jul-15 | controller |    1 |
|    531 | 03-Jul-15 | keyboard   |    3 |
|    531 | 06-Jul-15 | pen        |    2 |
|    531 | 10-Jul-15 | bowl       |    1 |
+--------+-----------+------------+------+
```

Each item has already been ranked based on their dates with a limit of 3 items per user. I have their last 3 items and the dates associated with them. The items can be anything.

I want to produce a view in a way that pivots the date and item combination. For example, the desired view for this table is:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| userid |   item1    |   date1   | item2 |   date2   |  item3   |   date3   |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|  34444 | controller | 09-Jul-15 | TV    | 04-Jul-15 | pen      | 01-Jul-15 |
|    531 | bowl       | 10-Jul-15 | pen   | 06-Jul-15 | keyboard | 03-Jul-15 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a pivot.  In more recent versions, you can use the actual `pivot` keyword.  Or in any version, you can just do

```
SELECT userid,
       max( case when rank = 1 then item else null end) item1,
       max( case when rank = 1 then date else null end) date1,
       max( case when rank = 2 then item else null end) item2,
       max( case when rank = 2 then date else null end) date2,
       max( case when rank = 3 then item else null end) item3,
       max( case when rank = 3 then date else null end) date3
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY userid
```